# How to call field from Serializers.py to views.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am learning it.

So there is a field called password in serializers.py
I want to call that field in views.py.
The password field is randomly generated.
I want to get this field.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

write serializer methods in serializers.py (like - add, update, list and all) and pass request data from views to serializer via context if you need to access request.user or request.data. And apply your logic in serializer.